# small caps in jquery using dropdown box

Tags: html

I am using following code but in it small caps is not working,please help me,see code
I am trying this in jquery,only small caps is not working.
I am using dropdown box for it.

```
<select id="size" >
  <option value="0">[No Engraving]</option>
  <option value="variant">Small Caps</option>
  <option value="uppercase">All Caps</option>
  <option value=" lowercase">No Caps</option>
  <option value="capitalize">Normal</option>
</select>
```

what you have answered its not working actually whenever I am writing into textbox and selecting any text transform from dropdown menu that text should be changed,If I am selecting all caps,no caps and normal its working very well only small caps is not working.(Remember I am doing all this in jquery.)
Please check this link and let me know why small caps is not working?and americana italic bt is also not working.

http://dwfek.hmnjw.servertrust.com/v/vspfiles/assets/images/Engraving%20Demo/jquery1.html

Comment: i edited your html code, so we can see it. please review and approve.

Comment: So what exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: Your link is dead. Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ for JavaScript examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing - What does small caps even mean?

I saw the site and the code used.
It seems to be using the selected option and onchange setting the 'text-transform' attribute of the text to the value of selected text.

From (W3schools)[http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp] allowed values are as follows:

```
text-transform: none;
text-transform: capitalize;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-transform: lowercase;
text-transform: inherit;
```

Thus your value 'variant' may not work.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose that your code will have somewhere something like (and you didnt show us that part)

```
font-variant:small-caps;
```

but as we can see there seems to be a typo, its **variant** not **varient**

make sure you didn't repeat that typo and if its all consistent